# Why is $\tau=1/k$ the time constant of an exponential decay $f(t)=e^{-kt}$

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, half-life

**Some context on why I came up with this question:**

I have to do a presentation on a paper about the heat equation on the cooling of a metal bar.

In this experiment, the general solution for the PDE is:

$T(x,t)=T_0+\frac{8\dot{Q}L}{KA\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos(\frac{\pi (2n+1)D}{2L}x)\exp[\frac{-\pi^2 (2n+1)^2}{4L^2}t]$

And as the decay of all the terms with $n \geq 1$ is much greater the thecay for the $n=0$ term, the expression can be simplified to:

$T(x,t)=T_0+\frac{8\dot{Q}L}{KA\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos(\frac{\pi }{2L}x)\exp[-\frac{\pi^2D }{4L^2}t]$

Once they get this expression, they say that the time constant is:

$\tau = \frac{4L^2}{\pi^2D}$

**The question itself:**

I know this would be the time so that the exponent term is $\exp[-\frac{\pi^2D }{4L^2}\tau]=e^{-1}$ and that this way you are getting the $\approx37\%$ of the initial value  but this seems rather arbitrary. If it was a lower percentage one could argue that it's the time requiered to consider an exponential decay process completed. However, 37% of the initial value seems like too much to consider completion.

I was wondering wether the choice for the definition of the time constant has any physical meaning or if its just for convenience as it's easy to compute.

I hope someone can help me understand this. Thanks in advence and sorry for any spelling or grammar mistakes I might have made, english is not my first language.

Comment: Presumably the summation in your second equation should also be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens a lot in physics that we look for a "characteristic" number for some quantity which only needs to be approximately the right order of magnitude, and is usually just taken from some very simple relationship.

However, in this case there is a more exact interpretation of the number $\tau$. This number is the average time taken to decay for an exponential distribution. In other words, if you sample a number from this exponential probability distribution over and over, and average all of the decay times together, that average value will approach $\tau$ as the number of samples increases $\to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just convenient, it's the mean lifetime. The lifetime has PDF $ke^{-kt}$ with support $\Bbb R^+$, which has mean $\int_0^\infty kte^{-kt}dt=\frac1k$.

Comment: That's right. Half-life is convenient, since dividing by 2 is easier than dividing by $e$.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the integral is on $kte^{-kt}$

Comment: @MikelSolaguren If $t$ has PDF $f$, you integrate $tf$ to get the mean of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

It is just convenient. $37\% = 1/e$ so it is a nice convenient number to use when you are using base $e$.

Answer (score 1):

What is required is an agreed characteristic time for a given process.

For a process which follows an exponential relationship the time constant $\tau$ is considered an easy to understand and useful parameter.
*If it was a lower percentage one could argue that it's the time requiered to consider an exponential decay process completed.*
So rule of thumb is to use five time constants by which time the value is less than $1\%$ of the original value.

Half life $t_{1/2} \,(= \ln2\,\tau$) could have been used and would perhaps be more intelligible to more people.